# When is $D^+(QC(X))$ not the same as $D_{qc}(X)^+$ for schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Let $QC(X)$ be the abelian category of quasicoherent sheaves on a scheme $X$. There is a functor
$$D^+(QC(X)) \to D_{qc}(X)^+$$
which is an isomorphism if $X$ is Noetherian or quasi-compact with affine diagonal. However, I don't know any examples where it is not an isomorphism. I'm curious about counterexamples both coming from non-quasi-compactness and coming from non-affine-diagonal.

In the cases where it is an isomorphism, it is shown by showing there are enough "true" injectives in $QC(X)$. And after the paper "Relative homological algebra in the category of quasi-coherent sheaves", it is known that there are enough injectives in $QC(X)$. So the only obstruction seems to me to be the possibility of an "fake" injective which is injective in the abelian category $QC(X)$ but not so in $D_{qc}(X)$, in the sense of a nonvanishing Ext group (necessarily in degree > 1 I think).

Comment: hi, what do you mean by $D_{qc}$?

Comment: I mean the category defined by Zariski descent of (stable) infinity-categories.It is also commonly defined as derived category of sheaves with quasi-coherent cohomologies.